# WCF RIA's (Silverlight Business Application Template) for Visual Studio 2013 missing

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2013, wcf-ria-services

I have a fresh install of Visual Studio 2013 (Ultimate) and I have downloaded and installed **WCF RIA Services Toolkit** from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=26939)

However when I create a new project under **Visual C#** -> **Silverlight** I don't find the **Silverlight Business Application** template in it.

On Google and on Stackoverflow I only see that the problem was earlier on the Visual Studio 2010 which required required SP1 and you were required to select the .Net Framework 4+.

What is the problem? Is there anything else missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That template was removed in VS2013
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161050.aspx

You can instead just use the basic Silverlight application template and add DomainServices manually as appropriate (the DomainServices wizard has also been removed).