# Missing "Add Domain Service Class" in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, wcf-ria-services

I have a Silverlight 5 app that I need to do maintenance work on. I'd like to avoid a VM.

With the release of .Net Framework 4.6.2 (in preview right now) [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1988437/) has been fixed, so it should be possible on my Win 10 machine.  I have VS2012 installed along with the WCF RIA Services V1.0 SP1 (and Toolkit) plus the Silverlight 5 SDK. The project builds and runs in VS2012...

But within VS2012 I'm missing the "Add New Domain Service Class" wizard, which I need for some comparative troubleshooting. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944139/wcf-rias-silverlight-business-application-template-for-visual-studio-2013-mis) and [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161050.aspx) the template was removed in VS2013 and VS2015, both of which I also have installed for other projects.

How can I get the "Add New Domain Service Class" wizard back in VS2012?

Comment: Not sure if you easily can, and in any case you're probably better off just looking for a sample to copy from. If it's an existing app, how come you need the wizard anyway? Isn't the domain service already there?

Comment: The DomainService is there, but the generated code is old and some things (including the database) have changed. I'd like to re-generate the DomainService and do some comparing. My workaround is a fresh VS2012 in a VM, and I think I'll just go that route.

Answer (score 1):

LightSwitch doesn't require much of the classes and projects that are created as part of the Domain Service Class Library template. Instead you can just:

Create a Class Library project

Add a reference to System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server assembly

Make your class inherit from the DomainService class found in the System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server namespace.

for more information [Creating a WCF RIA Service for Visual Studio LightSwitch 2013-2015](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/2226/Creating-a-WCF-RIA-Service-for-Visual-Studio-2013.aspx)